# get opened tabs title jquery easy ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm using [jQuery EasyUI tabs](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tabs.php). I'm trying to get the number of tabs that are opened by doing something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var tabs_title = [];
    $('#tab_id').tabs({
        onSelect: function (title, index) {
            tabs_title.push(title);
        }
    });
    console.debug(tabs_title);
});
```

When I do `console.debug(tabs_title)`, only the first tab title is shown in my array and I have five tabs. Does anybody know why I cannot get the title of the 5 tabs to be shown in my array when I select them please?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really have 5 _open_ tabs, or just 1 out of 5 selected?

Comment: I have 5 tabs I need to get the title only if they are opened. So If I open only 3 of them, I should have the 3 opened tabs title in my array, and so on

Comment: move your console log into the `onSelect`callback. As shown will only run on page load

Comment: I need my array `tabs_title` outside of the callback.

Answer (score 0):

onSelect is only fired when you select a tab. You should use onLoad which is fired whenever the tab loads.

```
$(function () {
    var tabs_title = [];
    $('#tab_id').tabs({
        onLoad: function (panel) {
            tabs_title.push(panel.title);
        }
    });
    console.debug(tabs_title);
});
```